# if $K \subset \mathbb R^{n}$ is compact and $f:K \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

I'm trying to formalize a proof for the above statement.

I have an idea for a proof but I'm unsure how the compact bit comes into play, or how to formalize the proof.

The idea of the proof is to choose two sequences that converge to the same limit $\{x_n\}, \{y_n\} \to L$

Then we have that $\forall \delta > 0,\exists N, \forall n > N, |x_n-L|<\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $|y_n-L|<\frac{\delta}{2}$

but $\delta > |x_n-L|+|y_n-L|=|x_n-L|+|L-y_n| \geq |x_n-L+L-y_n|=|x_n-y_n|$

So overall $|x_n-y_n| < \delta$

Now let's choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$.

if $f$ is continuous then this shouldn't be possible, since $x_n, y_n$ are allowed to get arbitrarily close, then $f(x_n),f(y_n)$ should also be arbitrarily close.

I feel like I'm in the right direction but I just need additional help filling in the gaps.

Comment: Why does this approach show that $f $ is uniformly continous? You seem to intend to prove this by contradiction, but I cannot see the negation of uniform continuity correctly spelled out in your reasoning. Your reasoning does, in fact, not use compactness of $K$. Without that assumption the statement is not true.

Answer (score 2):

Hint, Proof by contradiction gives you two sequences in which the distance of there n'th terms converges to zero. And since these two sequences lie entirely in the compact set $K$ they have convergent subsequences. Now by passing to those convergent subsequences you may assume (WLOG) $x_n , y_n$ converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively. Since these two sequences get close to each other as $n$ increases then you have $x=y=L$ that leads to a contradiction with $ 0=|f(x)-f(y)| \ge \epsilon$ (we knew $f$ is continuous)

Comment: let me see if I understand. If $x_n, y_n$ are sequences that are entirely in a compact set (closed and bounded) then these sequences are bounded. By Bolzano-Weierstrass they each have convergent subsequences. This is kind of where I lost you. is $x_n$ the subsequence or the original? Why must we have that the subsequences get close to each other as $n$ increases? this is only true if the main sequences converge to the same limit

Comment: it is subsequence .  
2) If you could understand the negation of uniformly continuous precisely then you will get why they get closed to each other.... I meant  " the distance of their n'th terms converges to zero"